# Why I am not able to receive data in my adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

This code is in my MainActivity.java and I am able to print title in log cat from here

```
feedsDataArray = feedsData.toArray(feedsDataArray);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < feedsDataArray.length ; i++){
            Log.v("Array",feedsDataArray[i].getTitle());
        }

listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
feedsAdapter = new FeedsAdapter(NewsFeedsActivity.this, R.layout.feeds_list,
            feedsDataArray);
listview.setAdapter(feedsAdapter);
```

But when I am passing it to adapter then I am not able to get data there

```
public class FeedsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FeedsItems>{

    Context context;
    int id;
    FeedsItems [] dataArray;

    public FeedsAdapter(Context context, int id,FeedsItems [] dataArray) {
        super(context,id);

        this.context = context;
        this.id = id;
        this.dataArray = dataArray;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        FeedsHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {                  

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater(); 
            row = inflater.inflate(id, parent, false);
            holder = new FeedsHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.feeds_image);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.feeds_title);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (FeedsHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        //holder.imgIcon.setImageResource();
        holder.txtTitle.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
        Log.v("Title"+position,dataArray[position].getTitle());

        return row;
    }

    static class FeedsHolder{
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }


}
```

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated. Thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to override `getCount` and let it returns `dataArray.lenght` or pass `dataArray` to the `ArrayAdapter`'s super constructor.

Take a look the the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29)

Comment: may be `super(context,id,dataArray);`

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks. I was looking for the constructor in the documentation :)

Comment: was about to post it as an answer but you beat me by few seconds. As always you are super fast

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your adapter class...

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataArray.length;
    }
```